# Coefficients in a Randomized Block Design

Tags: generalized-linear-model, experiment-design, intercept, regression-coefficients, blocking

If, for example, I am running a GLM with Poisson distribution (it could be any distribution) and I have a Randomized Block Design (RBD) [Note: I don't wanna run a GLMM just to put the blocks as a random effect]. So my model would be `VARIABLE ~ TREATMENTS + BLOCKS`. Because of that, R estimates the coefficients for the treatments and the blocks. The problem is that in the intercept is adding the effect of the first treatment with the first block, and I am not interested in the block coefficients for the model.

How can I isolate the effects of the first treatment without the first block in the intercept?